# How to set the color of finding Occurrence of key words in PhpStorm?

Tags: colors, phpstorm, setting

I have an issue about how to set the color of finding Occurrence of key words in PhpStorm. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are using some custom editor schema -- please try unmodified Darcula -- any better?

Comment: Thanks buddies! I just download the latest version: Version: 10.0.3 then restart it and choose the Darcula, then it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Change color for specific 'find View' is not possible.

This color area is link by the color of editor. Change color in Editor and your result find view change also with those color you specified.

This is what your color change when you changed the theme of PHPStorm.